# Unable to read Jquery,css, in Apache web server in linux Operating syetem

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat, servlets

[image]This my Project plz see the screen.[image]

same code i have deployed in apace tomcat server in Linux operating system. in that i am unable to open data calender popup windows [date calender is coming using jquery code]
Window Os deployed project Output:
looking like this 
[image]

Linux Os deployed project Output:
and also some of function is not working which is related to java scrip and Jquery css or html plz help me is there any change we ll have to do in Linux Os. in tomcat server in windows is working perfect .

please check i have Update see my command Linux unable to change file permission

Comment: Its all related to your browser, fix your js and css

Comment: But i have checked in more than 20 pc Browser in all its coming like this same code which i deployed in windows apache tomcat server its working fine and every thing coming correct but this Problem is coming on Linux os apache tomcat server

Comment: check folder names of web subsfolders, any special chars oder white spaces? css / js folders i mean

Comment: That should work fine .Check your browser console. I guess problem might be that your some of your js or css might not be loading up .e.g might be jquery

Comment: yes agree with @DhruvPal, you should install firebug or some other debuging plugin and check the error

Comment: Are your paths configured correctly on the Linux machine?

Comment: why this issue coming for linux while windows its working fine . yes i have checked that unable to read in linux.what will be solution is any thing we ll have On In Linux ?

Comment: which file/s cannot be read? post stack or consol log please

Comment: Jqueryfile css file..

Comment: access error or parsing error? where do you see this error? in tomcat or Browswer console?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: locNamearray is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: f_clientHeight is not defined   this Error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, jQuery and css are client side script there is nothing to do with server, please check your js and css file path so that you can trace the issue.

Comment: yaar its working fine In windows OS ok just check  same java jsp html csse code [project ] deploye in linux os then it unable to read  client side code in return the page looking like that which is coming in top of second image which is not coming Properly.

Answer (score 0):

possible reasons:

1) js Files are unaccessable, open Terminal und and check the permissions of these files.

2) sometimes if you edit files in windows with some editors, it appends a lot of "windows" special chars. open these files in eclipse and check this too. this causes parsing error.

Comment: navigate to the folder and list its contents: ls -l

Comment: So from this command   permission will allow ? so can i check now?

Comment: no this command displays its mode only. post result of ls -l please

Comment: Nobody nobody 34381 dec 13 11:08 jscal2.js  this coming  when use ls-l command so i will give this file read permission ?

Comment: try to change its mod to 0644: chmod 0644 jscal2.js

Comment: chmod 0644 jscal2.js this command run but not change the Permission .what i have to now ?

Comment: stop tomcat first, check parents folders of jscal2.js. which mod does it have? the full tree (all parents folder), try it with sudo chmod ...., so you act as root, after chaging it, list the contents again with ls -l to see if jscal2.js has read permission

Comment: please check i have added image i am unable to change file permission while i have use same command its running But not changed file permission

Comment: you can change the ownership and the group of this file with this command: chown root yourfile and the group with chgrp root yourfile, but i don't think that this is the cause of your problem

Answer (score 0):

hey dude I had the same problem that WIN OS server worked well but when I change OS to Linux Centos Server I had problem in reading files for example my file was DatePicker.js but in my code I added datepicker.js so in WIN OS worked good because WIN in not Case sensitive but Centos is.
so I change my code to DatePicker.js and it works.